# Is it possible to always smash the big prize Piñata in Plants vs Zombies 2

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

When you finish a daily Piñata Party you are presented with a screen of Piñata's to smash. There are four rows of four. After you smash your allocated three Piñata's then if you haven't revealed the big prize pot of coins (or costume if you've not unlocked them all) then it's location is revealed. I have noticed that it's location is not random, instead it appears to be decided based on your choices.

I'm going to give some 'for instances' from memory, so I might not be 100% right, but it's definitely not random for me. For instance if I pick #1, #2 and #4 along the bottom row then the big coin pot will appear in position #3. If I pick #1, #2, #3 then the prize Piñata will be #4. That sort of thing.

So my question is, has anyone discovered a sequence of three Piñata's to smash that always includes the big coin pot?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it's not random.  When I pick # 12, 16, 15. The jackpot prize is on 14. 
 I've also played this challange an average of 6 days a week for 6 months.  I've hit the jackpot 2 times in all.  And the odds should be 3/16.  Statistically, the number of timesI should have hit the jackpot should be somewhere in the 20´s not just 2 times.

I've started trying different sequences to try and find a pattern, but I've only stumbled across the one I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it is truly random. You will *NEVER* get the jackpot in your first two pinatas - prizes are equal or increase in value as you open them. Most of the time you'll hear two normal whacks, then a more "deluxe" whack sound on your 3rd pinata.

Because you'll never hit the jackpot on your first or second try, it's statistically impossible for said jackpot to be locked in place or genuinely random. I don't know the inner workings or the programming code behind pinata parties, but I'm willing to go out on a limb here and say that the game determines how often you hit the jackpot, and it does not matter which pinatas you whack.

Currently the only way to guarantee yourself the 3500 coins or a new costume is by playing the pinata party 5 days in a row for an opportunity to whack senor pinata. That giant zombie head always contains a costume or the 3500 gold jackpot.

Comment: Yeah I've been playing the daily party for months now and haven't received a jackpot in weeks. Hence me starting to notice patterns.